# How to pass Json object to Jenkins power shell script as a input parameter

Tags: json, xml, powershell, jenkins

Dears,

We are in the process of executing set of power shell scripts which is present in client machines remotely. We have list of IP Address's for the client machines as a JSON or XML object.

We need to pass JSON or XML object to Jenkins job, through which JENKINS will read the IP Address and credentials to execute the scripts. After reading the list of IP Address will be passed as a parameter to execute scripts in client machines.

Please help us in resolving the same as early.

Comment: read as file or pass it as text?

Comment: It should be read as a file. Since the output will be of a JSON or XML File format

Comment: so whats the problem, read the file and parse it?